# How do I clear a leaflet map in react so I can map fresh data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am attempting to clear a leaflet map in react when fetching new data to map, and i am unsure how to approach this. I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62166577/how-to-clear-leaflet-map-in-reactjs-by-button) but not sure how exactly to apply it.

Right now I have a function that fetches 1 of 2 geojsons I have loaded.

**App.js**

```
//SWAP FILES AS EXAMPLE
  fetchData = () => {
    //MAP SHOULD CLEAR EVERYTIME NEW DATA IS FETCHED
    if(this.state.loaded === 1) {
      fetch(
        "https://raw.githack.com/datafaust/raw/main/cruise-prototype/hh_2020112300_2020120623_Saturday_02.geojson"
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((geojson) => {
          this.setState({ geojson, loaded: 2 });
        });

    } else {
      fetch(
        "https://raw.githack.com/datafaust/raw/main/cruise-prototype/hh_2020112300_2020120623_Saturday_03.geojson"
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((geojson) => {
          this.setState({ geojson, loaded: 1 });
        });
    } 
  };
```

This is merely a test to get the functionality down. Right now if I click the `fetch data button` after the initial load, leaflet maps the new geojson on top. How would I clear the mapped information so that the new geojson is mapped fresh?

I have a code sand box here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-test-forked-8hm3i?file=/src/Leaf.js:550-573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable outside `Choro` component.

```
let savedGeojson = {};
```

Inside useEffect make it equal with the `L.choropleth` instance. If it exists remove the geojson from the map else save the new one by replacing the last saved.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(props.geojson).length > 0) {
      if (savedGeojson) map.removeLayer(savedGeojson);
      savedGeojson = L.choropleth(props.geojson, {
        valueProperty: "DIFF", // which property in the features to use
        scale: ["white", "red"], // chroma.js scale - include as many as you like
        steps: 5, // number of breaks or steps in range
        mode: "q", // q for quantile, e for equidistant, k for k-means
        //style,
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
          layer.bindPopup(
            "Total " + feature.properties.DIFF + "<br>" //+
            // feature.properties.incidents.toLocaleString() +
            // " incidents"
          );
        }
      }).addTo(map);
    }
  }, [props.geojson]);

  return null;
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-do-i-clear-a-leaflet-map-in-react-so-i-can-map-fresh-data-bso6s?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Side note: with a single variable in file scope outside the React component, it will work fine only for 1 instance of that component. If it needs to be instantiated more than once, you should use a state instead, so that each instance has its own reference.

Comment: Sounds correct. To be honest for this specific example I was not thinking that this component will be used more than once but in case it will be it is good to have that in mind, so thanks for pointing it out.